# Magento 2 : Get Configurable Product using swatch-option

Tags: magento2, product, category, attributes, configurable-swatches

I want to get product id on selecting swatch option.for that i have used code as given below.
i am getting error of "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'options')" as per given screenshot.i am using Magento 2.4.4.
if i print simple console.log(" hello world ") using this Js code this will execute but for select options it throws error.

error:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAsgD.png

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/default.phtml

```
<script>
    requirejs(['jquery','underscore','Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils','mage/url'],
        function(jQuery,_,flooring,priceUtils,urlBuilder){
        jQuery(window).on('load',function(){
            jQuery( ".product-options-wrapper div" ).click(function() {
                selpro();
            });
        });
        function selpro () {
            var selected_options = {};
            jQuery('div.swatch-attribute').each(function(k,v){
                var attribute_id    = jQuery(v).attr('data-attribute-id');
                var option_selected = jQuery(v).attr('data-option-selected');
                if(!attribute_id || !option_selected){ return;}
                selected_options[attribute_id] = option_selected;
            });
            
            var product_id_index = jQuery('[data-role=swatch-options]').data('mageSwatchRenderer').options.jsonConfig.index;
            var found_ids = [];
            jQuery.each(product_id_index, function(product_id,attributes){
                var productIsSelected = function(attributes, selected_options){
                    return _.isEqual(attributes, selected_options);
                }
                if(productIsSelected(attributes, selected_options)){
                    found_ids.push(product_id);
                }
            });
            var new_found_ids = found_ids[0];             
        }
    });
</script>
```

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
           <referenceBlock name="product.info.configurable">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::product/view/type/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code work for me you can try it.

app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Extension_Plugin_ConfigurableProduct_Block_Product_View_Type_Configurable" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable"/>
    </type>
 
    <type name="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Extension_ConfigurableSkuSwitch_Plugin_Magento_Swatches_Block_Product_Renderer_Configurable" sortOrder="10" type=" Vendor \ Extension \Plugin\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type;
 
class Configurable
{
 
    public function afterGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        $result
    ) {
 
    $jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);
    $jsonResult['skus'] = [];
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
            $jsonResult['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
    }
    $result = json_encode($jsonResult);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Extension\Plugin\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer;
 
class Configurable
{
    public function afterGetJsonConfig(\Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable $subject, $result) {
 
        $jsonResult = json_decode($result, true);
        $jsonResult['skus'] = [];
 
        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $simpleProduct) {
           $jsonResult['skus'][$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getSku();
        }
        $result = json_encode($jsonResult);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_ConfigurableProduct/js/configurable': {
                'Vendor_Extension/js/model/skuswitch': true
            },
            'Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer': {
                'Vendor_Extension/js/model/swatch-skuswitch': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\web\js\model\skuswitch.js

```
    define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
 
    return function(targetModule){
 
        var reloadPrice = targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice;
        var reloadPriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(reloadPrice, function(original){
        var result = original();
        var simpleSku = this.options.spConfig.skus[this.simpleProduct];
 
            if(simpleSku != '') {
                $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);
            }
            return result;
        });
        targetModule.prototype._reloadPrice = reloadPriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

app\code\Vendor\Extension\view\frontend\web\js\model\swatch-skuswitch.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/utils/wrapper'
], function ($, wrapper) {
    'use strict';
 
    return function(targetModule){
        var updatePrice = targetModule.prototype._UpdatePrice;
        targetModule.prototype.configurableSku = $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html();
        var updatePriceWrapper = wrapper.wrap(updatePrice, function(original){
            var allSelected = true;
            for(var i = 0; i<this.options.jsonConfig.attributes.length;i++){
                if (!$('div.product-info-main .product-options-wrapper .swatch-attribute.' + this.options.jsonConfig.attributes[i].code).attr('data-option-selected')){
                    allSelected = false;
                }
            }
            var simpleSku = this.configurableSku;
            if (allSelected){
                var products = this._CalcProducts();
                simpleSku = this.options.jsonConfig.skus[products.slice().shift()];
            }
            $('div.product-info-main .sku .value').html(simpleSku);
              return original();
        });
 
        targetModule.prototype._UpdatePrice = updatePriceWrapper;
        return targetModule;
    };
});
```

Note: this will update SKU on selection you can modify as per your need.

Comment: Thank You..It's Working..!!